# WKWebview to send YES always for network check?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, webkit, wkwebview

If the page loaded in the `WKwebview` tries to check the network availability using `window.navigator.isonline`, it should always return `yes` even if the device is not connected to the internet.

I don't have access to the content`(javascript/ html/ css)` loaded in the WKwebview
Is it possible to achieve this by changing any property of `WKWebview`?

For example: In Android we have the option `webview.setNetworkAvailable(true)`. Is there any similar option in iOS?

Comment: No. But I'll bite, why?

Comment: Just to redirect the requests to my local HTTP server so that I can provide data to Webview for offline usage.

Comment: I thought you said you don't have access to the content? I'm sure you can imagine how intercepting and redirecting `WKWebView` requests without the end-user being aware of it isn't a good API for apple to provide.

Comment: I have the source code for the content loaded in the webview but my requirement is I should not modify anything in the source code. The javascript files will request for resources like images/json/css/HTML as HTTP request and I ll serve them using the HTTP server running in my device...My server is running in my app and the client is my webview.